# I am not getting the connected bluetooth devices in didDiscoverPeripheral method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am getting the disconnected bluetooth devices in the `- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI` method but not getting the connected bluetooth devices in the same code. Here is the code for scan the bluetooth devices.

```
- (int)scanForPeripherals {
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey,
                             nil];

    [bluetoothManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(stopDiscoverPairing)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried the `didReadRSSI` method but that was also not worked. Kindly let me know if anyone've faced this problem and got the solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need connected device which you have already connected? Because didDiscoverPeripheral only search the not connected BLE Device.

Comment: I want to display that list in the app and also want to know that any device is connected or not. If that is connected then want to trigger some action.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518924-retrieveconnectedperipherals ?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much for the reply. I'll look into this and will let you know if this will helpful for me. :) Thanks again.